# Count Number of files on FTP from SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, ftp, sql-server-2008-r2

I've tried searching for this but haven't found any good results.

I'm trying to use T-SQL from SQL Server 2008 to create a FTP connection using a username and password and to count the number of files in particular directory.

Any help would be great.

Comment: if you can list files with command prompt, you can use `xp_cmdshell`  procedure.

Comment: The best I know is to use `xp_cmdshell` to call the `ftp` command to handle the FTP itself. But it's really a **bad** idea to even try it, it's much better to do it client-side instead.

Comment: I think you're right I'm just going to use asp.net to use a ftpwebrequest instead of trying to manipulate sql server and command prompt to get me the values. Thanks.

Comment: The best way I suggest to you is to create a CLR procedure to accomplish this task